# Should tags be internationalized?

Tags: internationalisation, localization, tags, tagging

Concerning Tags, like on stackexchange, or like in a webapp for creating content, would it be useful to store their name in a localized way: `name:{en:'something', de:'someth...', ..}` instead of `name:'something'`?. The language values could possibly be the same than `en` (default).

Should it rather be all english, or a multi-language name, searchable per language?

What are the risk, or advantage of i18n for tags?

Comment: Aren't all the pages in English? Would there be any gain in allowing people to search only the tags in languages other than English?

Comment: @Alvaro will answer this question. He's got a lot in his pocket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Multiple languages is fine as long as each tag has only one language.

Allowing tags in different languages isn't the same as having translations for each tag.

Translations for tags can be very inconsistent, as they are tags in the end, their purpose is to group unstructured/unpredictable content together.

Tags has certain meaning for a certain group of people, and is likely limited to their cultures and languages. Often we go to twitter and do not understand what a specific hashtag means, imagine how weird it becomes if twitter enabled hashtag translations, they are still **tags** in the end - debatable.

take a look at this http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/Tag

If the case was **categories**, translations make sense, where the structure is predefined, managed and most likely fixed from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks, intereresting answer, the tags would be managed, editable, not completely unstructured like keywords

Comment: Most welcome, I think you are referring to categories, i will update my answer soon to explain more about them. The short answer is "Go for it".